# Setting environmental variable in linux via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, login, environment-variables, bash

I am working on three different issues so I have cloned source code in three different directories.

```
1) /nobackup/vivek/dev1/<source_code>..
2) /nobackup/vivek/dev2/<source_code>..
3) /nobackup/vivek/dev3/<source_code>..
```

I have made few aliases in `.bashrc` file for few modules so that I can jump to them quickly. I have used environmental variable named as `CDR` whose value can be `dev1`, `dev2` or `dev3` depending on which issue and directory I am working.

Example of one of the alias from my `.bashrc` file

```
alias acl='cd /nobackup/vivek/$CDR/<source_code>../acl'
```

Right now I have to change the value of the environmental variable manually. For example , if I want to work on issue no. 3 then I have to export the environmental variable `CDR` to `dev3`.

```
export CDR=dev3.
```

Because for issue no. 3, I should be under `dev3` folder i.e. `/nobackup/vivek/dev3/<source_code>..`

Similary if I am working on issue no. 1 or 2 I have to export the environmental variable manually to `dev1` or `dev2`

```
export CDR=dev1 or export CDR=dev2
```

I thought to set the environmental variable `CDR` at the time of ssh itself. I have tried below command to accomplish that

```
ssh -t vgagiot@122.11.33.21 'export CDR=dev1'
or
ssh -t vgagiot@122.11.33.21 'export CDR=dev2'
```

When I execute the above ssh commands, my connection gets terminated as soon as I enter the password.

vgagiot@122.11.33.21's password:
Connection to 122.11.33.21 closed.

Can anyone please help me here. I am not sure why my connection getting terminated. Is there any other way by which I can set my env variable at the time of login itself.

Comment: If you add -v to your ssh command, what is the verbose output?

Comment: You connect and run a command. When the command is done, the connection is closed. This is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to start `bash` (or your preferred shell) - best as login shell, to ensure your standard profile, rc-file etc. are loaded, too:

```
ssh -t user@server "export var=VALUE ; bash -l"
```

Or as pointed out by @they, the shorter notation

```
ssh -t user@server "var=VALUE bash -l"
```

will do, too.

Comment: Just running `var=VALUE bash -l` remotely would be shorter and do the same thing.